# How to check if an element exists to not duplicate it in a collection of controls in C#?

Tags: c#

I am trying to make list in c# where data is getting from mysql database. I have created code but it seems like duplicating received item how can I pass this without duplicate (or add only once)?

```
cmpSearchItem[] listItems = new cmpSearchItem[10];

for (int i = 0; i < listItems.Length; i++)
{
    listItems[i] = new cmpSearchItem();
    listItems[i].Width = container_main.Width;
    listItems[i].cmpID = cmpId;
    listItems[i].cmpName = cmpName;
    listItems[i].cmpDescription = cmpDescription;
    listItems[i].cmpMembers = cmpMembers + "/32";
    listItems[i].cmpCountry = cmpCountry;
    listItems[i].cmpCreated = cmpCreated;

    container_main.Controls.Add(listItems[i]);
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the query you are sending to the database. How do you identify duplicate entries in the result from MySQL? Do you use the `DISTINCT` keyword?

Comment: Using `find` and `contains` as lambda you can check whether it is in the list or not ... Detaisl can be seen [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.find?view=netcore-3.1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should verify if the item is not present in the collection before adding it, in case of the collection does not do that for you (check the documentation or the implementation of the method of the class used):

```
if ( !container_main.Controls.Contains(listItems[i]) )
  container_main.Controls.Add(listItems[i]);
```

Comment: It does work but it won't read first row from database. Anyway thanks.

Comment: Don't hesitate to create a new question if you have another problem. have a good job and enjoy coding in C#!

Answer (score 0):

`Container_main` is a collection.

Therefore before doing the `.Add` simply do an:

```
if ( container_main.Contains() == false )
```

Comment: Prefer writing `if ( !container_main.Contains() )` (democratic convention).